# cannot assign port in url while requesting to server in android

Tags: android, json, url

i am creating android app where i need to pass url with port as "http://182.71.155142:8888" but when i request for this url from android app using loopj Library .It shows me exception and Exception is:

> Unable to resolve host "nsg-static-142.155.71.182.airtel.in": No address associated with hostname

Can anyone help me how to pass port number so that i can get response from url

i am sending the request by using following code:

> AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient(8888);
>   client.get("http://182.71.155.142/demo/loan-lelo/json/1",params,new AsyncHttpResponseHandler()

i am able to hit url from browser and getting response 
by this way i am hitting url "http://182.71.155.142:8888/demo/loan-lelo/json/loan-details/1"

Comment: Try specifying 8888 port as well in the URL.

Answer (score 1):

Try using any other library. I tried with OKHttp Library and works properly for me in my case.

Comment: may i know the reason

Comment: I did not try loopj so I am not aware of it may be in general we hit the parameters in body or using concatenation there might be some other way like www-form-urlencoded or something else when url is with port.
You can try for this it ll work and let me know too.

Comment: i tried okhttp , it works fine with port .but i want to know y not in loopj